# why is it incorrect to say I felt/ was feeling the discomfort?

Tags: sentence-construction

If I can say 'You cannot feel my pain' why can't I say 'He felt the discomfort in the party'?

Comment: "To feel the discomfort" is grammatical, why do you think it is not correct?

Comment: "He felt the party's discomfort" is more natural English.  But otherwise it's fine to say something like this.

Comment: Semantically, the two usages are significantly different. *I feel your pain* asserts that I *[viscerally, internally] **experience*** the pain you're going through, but *I felt* [more likely, ***sensed**] the anger of the crowd* simply asserts that I was *aware of the existence* of said anger - probably through some unspecified "non-obvious" sensory channel.

Comment: Please clarify what meaning you are trying to convey. Do you mean "party" as in "the other person", or "party" as in "a fun get-together"? Do you mean he felt his own discomfort or someone else's? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: The sentence is grammatically correct but extremely ambiguous.  Say *He felt the party's discomfort*, *He felt uncomfortable being in the party*, or *He felt uncomfortable at the party*, depending on what you mean.

**Longer Answer:**

The first sentence ('No one can feel my pain') uses a possessive (*my*) to clarify where the pain resides.  The second sentence ('He felt the discomfort in the party') is awkward because it's unclear who is uncomfortable.

- If the party is uncomfortable, and 'He' sensed their discomfort, use a possessive phrase of some type to make that clear: *He felt the party's discomfort.*
- If 'He' is uncomfortable, a native speaker would probably say 'He felt uncomfortable'.  This is the easiest way to fix this sentence if 'He' is the one who is uncomfortable: *He felt uncomfortable in the party* (see in vs at later).
- As a side note, let's look at 'in the party' vs 'at the party'.  The choice of preposition changes the meaning of 'party'.  Say 'in the party' if the party is a group of people.  Say 'at the party' if the party is an event.
- You can still stick with 'discomfort' instead of 'uncomfortable', even if 'He' is the one who is uncomfortable, although a native speaker normally would not choose this option.  If you want to use the word 'discomfort', do not use the word 'the' with it.  You would only use the definite article 'the' if you are referring to a specific discomfort, and which discomfort will be explained elsewhere in the sentence.  The rest of the sentence is "in the party," so using the word 'the' implies the party is feeling uncomfortable. 
  Unfortunately, leaving out the word 'the' isn't enough to get rid of the ambiguity of who is feeling discomfort.  To fully clarify while still using the word 'discomfort' instead of 'uncomfortable', you have to add the word 'being' to make it clear it isn't the discomfort in the party:  *He felt discomfort being in the party.*  The meaning of this sentence is clear, although a native speaker would be unlikely to say it this way.  Maybe *Being in the party caused him discomfort*?  At any rate, you can include "being" in the other versions of the sentence to further clarify that it is the state of being in/at the party that is causing discomfort:  *He felt uncomfortable being in the party.*